# Not assigning data from java VO to Flex VO using cairngorm

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, cairngorm

I have a few values in Java VO, and using cairgorm framework, i had mapping the Java VO to Action script VO in Flex and given same variables name as java Vo variables name. Now the Vo is mapping fine and when looking the result all variables are displaying as null. Can i know the reason for that.Java returning list of VO's.

```
package com.configuration
{
    import com.adobe.cairngorm.vo.IValueObject;
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection; import mx.resources.ResourceManager;

    [Bindable]
    [RemoteClass(alias='com.configuration.ProgressState')]
    public class ProgressState implements IValueObject
    {
        public function ProgressState(){}
        public var ssn:String;
        public var objectType:ObjectTypeEnum;
        public var totalObjectCount:int;
        public var completedObjectCount:int;
        public var failedObjectCount:int;
        public static const TOTAL_COUNT_NOT_SET:int = -1;
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: Use the edit link and add the code inside your question, don't forget to format it properly

Comment: I don't understand this statement: "Now the Vo is mapping fine and when looking the result all variables are displaying as null."  Are you sure the VOs are mapping fine if the results of all variables are null?

Comment: i got the issue. no setter methods in the java VO, so the data is not assigned to the flex VO. i would like to thanks to all to participate and involving for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use charles proxy to view server response in AMF format

[charles proxy website](http://www.charlesproxy.com)

Comment: Or Service Capture; or the Flash Builder Network Monitor.  Either of those may be great troubleshooting tools, however I don't believe this actually answers the question.